# ¿Cómo puedo relacionar alumnos con cursos desde un select en laravel 8?

Tags: javascript, html, laravel, laravel-8

Estoy intentando crear un sistema de matricula en laravel, al momento de iniciar la matricula tiene que tener los cursos/grados creados en otro crud, ya que en el momento del formulario de alumnos tengo un select que pregunta a que grado o curso va el niño este es el select:

```html
   <div class="form-row">
          <div class="col-md-4 mb-3">
            <label for="curso_id">Curso</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="curso_id" name="curso_id">
        <option value="">Seleccionar un curso</option>
        @foreach ($cursos as $id => $curso)
            <option value="{{ $id }}">{{ $curso }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
          </div>
```

se supone que estan relacionadas alumnos con cursos tanto en migraciones como en modelos:
Migracion de alumnos:

```
Schema::create('alumnos', function (Blueprint $table) {
       --------------datos del alumno------------
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('curso_id');
        $table->foreign('curso_id')->references('id')->on('cursos')->before('created_at');
```

en el controlador de la matricula tengo esto:

```
public function creatematricula()
{
    $cursos = Curso::pluck('curso', 'id');
    $alumno = new Alumno();
    return view('secretaria.matricula.datosalumno',compact('alumno','cursos'));
}
```

y en el metodo store:

```
  $cursos = $request->input('curso_id');

  $alumno = Alumno::create([
    -----datos alumnos----
    'curso_id' => $cursos,
]);

      session(['alumno_id' => $alumno->id]);
      


      return redirect()->route('datospadre.create');
```

El problema dice que:

```
 SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'curso_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `alumnos` (`primernombre`, `segundonombre`, `primerapellido`, `segundoapellido`, `numerodeidentidad`, `fechadenacimiento`, `alergia`, `genero`, `direccion`, `numerodehermanosenicgc`, `fotografias`, `fotografiasdelpadre`, `carnet`, `certificadodeconducta`, `ciudad`, `depto`, `pais`, `escuelaanterior`, `totalhermanos`, `medico`, `telefonoemergencia`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (Oscar, Luis, ale, Verseti, 0703199904682, 2023-05-05, ?, masculino, Danli, El Paraiso, 1, ?, ?, ?, ?, Danli, El Paraiso, Honduras, Nicaragua, 3, medico, 31313131, 2023-04-14 20:00:24, 2023-04-14 20:00:24))
```

Lo que significa que la id del curso no se esta recibiendo correctamente, y no encuentro el error, ¿Alguien que sepa mejor que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Comprueba $request->input('curso_id'); antes de ingresarlo a la base

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto suele pasar si el modelo no tiene incluido el valor a actualizar dentro del `$fillable` del modelo:

```
class Alumno extends Model{
...
protected $fillable = [... ,'curso_id'];
...
}
```

Esto creo que es lo que ocurre en tu código, también comprueba que $cursos no sea nulo por si acaso.

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano.